# What is the "binary representation" of a vector of nominal data?

Tags: matrices, statistics

In statistics, nominal data (synonymous with categorical data) is merely data that has no natural ordering and has no quantitative meaning. For example: gender - which in most surveys, has two states: male and female. I could sample a bunch of people and ask them for their gender, and analyze these data. But there is no natural ordering of male vs. female. (This is in contrast to qualitative "ordinal" data, where ordering does matter - for example, how happy are you?) See [here](http://www.mymarketresearchmethods.com/types-of-data-nominal-ordinal-interval-ratio/) for further details.

Suppose I have a vector of nominal data 
$$\mathbf{u} = \begin{bmatrix}
U_1 \\
U_2 \\
\vdots \\ 
U_D\end{bmatrix}\text{.}$$
This journal article I have says to let $$\mathbf{x} = \begin{bmatrix}
X_1 \\
X_2 \\
\vdots \\
X_S
\end{bmatrix}$$
be the **binary representation** of $\mathbf{u}$, where each $U_d$ has $s_d$ possible states, $d = 1, \dots, D$.

Obviously there must be $\prod_{d=1}^{D}s_d$ possible states for a particular value of $\mathbf{u}$. What I don't understand is why $S = \prod_{d=1}^{D}s_d$. I would think $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{x}$ would have the same dimension (take a particular value of $\mathbf{u}$ and translate each of its components to a binary 0/1 variable... right?) but this clearly isn't the case.

The journal article in question is [this article](http://people.ucalgary.ca/~adeleon/JMVA_mahalanobis.pdf). No other context is given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "binary", the article means that

1. $\forall i\,\,X_i\in\{0, 1\}.$ (Components are binary).
2. $\exists{!}\,i\in\{1,...,S\}: X_i=1.$ (One and only one coordinate is 1).

Obviously, the number of such $X$'s is $N$ if and only if it has $N$ coordinates. Thus, since $U$ can take on $S$  values and it is in a one-to-one correspondense with $X$, $X$ must have $S$ coordinates.

That being set, this "binary representation" is definitely not unique since we can freely change the order of the coordinates.

Comment: Thank you for the last sentence, in particular. I was wondering about uniqueness especially. +10 when this system lets me